# Cursor with Variable - does not stop executing - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have a stored procedure that is suppose to grab a login that is older than 24 hours old and drops it. I have added a cursor to loop through the master.sys.sql_logins so that it picks up all the logins that needs to be dropped.

However when I run this stored procedure, it never stops executing and it only returns one login when it is suppose to return two as shown below:

[image]

Not sure why it does that, but here is the script:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @RandomChar VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @DropTemp   NVARCHAR(500)

--Grabs the last two right characters where login name is older than 24 hours
DECLARE RandomChar_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT RandomChar = RIGHT(RTRIM(name), 2) FROM master.sys.sql_logins WHERE name LIKE '%tempIMPLUSER%' AND create_date > DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) -1, 0)

OPEN RandomChar_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM RandomChar_Cursor INTO
    @RandomChar

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN

        SET @DropTemp = 'DROP LOGIN tempIMPLUser' + @RandomChar
        print @droptemp
            --EXEC sp_executesql @DropTemp

    END

CLOSE RandomChar_Cursor
DEALLOCATE RandomChar_Cursor

END
```

Comment: You have the sql equivalent of `for(var i = 0;i<Infinity;i++){}`

Comment: Better idea...don't use a cursor at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also run fetch the next value from the cursor within the loop, as well as before the loop begins.

Change your loop to:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    SET @DropTemp = 'DROP LOGIN tempIMPLUser' + @RandomChar
    print @droptemp
        --EXEC sp_executesql @DropTemp
    FETCH NEXT FROM RandomChar_Cursor INTO @RandomChar

END
```

Comment: Wow I'm dumb, thanks. I'll accept the answer in 10 mins!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a cursor here. You can do so this so much simpler by using dynamic sql for this type of administration thing. It is easier to code and doesn't require all the complications of looping. Once you are satisfied the dynamic sql string is correct you can simply uncomment the exec line.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'DROP LOGIN ' + name + ';' 
FROM master.sys.sql_logins 
WHERE name LIKE '%tempIMPLUSER%' 
AND create_date > DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) -1, 0)

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: **MUCH BETTER IDEA!** Plus one

Answer (score 1):

To avoid writing (and changing in the future) two fetch statements I do:

```
WHILE (1=1) BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM RandomChar_Cursor INTO @RandomChar
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK
    ... use @RandomChar
END
```